# List view under tab

Tags: android, listview, uitabview

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class HelloAndroid extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3"));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

 // Find the ListView resource.   
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lstMain);  

    // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                                      "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

    // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
   listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, planetList);  

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 


 // End


}
```

}

and here is the code for my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a third tab" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstMain" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: @varunkhanduja: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's way too much code here, in your question, though. Consider including ONLY the code that's part of the problem. Otherwise, paste for reference over at http://pastbin.com

Comment: Holy crap you're doing a lot of things wrong. Maybe you should try to get a tab activity working before you try to put fancy stuff inside the tabs.

Comment: Thanks @p.campbell and @Falmarri. I tried to edit the comment just to have the code. I will work on your suggestion as well @Falmarri. Is there any input you have for something else which may have possibly gone wrong? Sorry I m still learning Android so I m sure my question must be quite silly :) Thank you.

Comment: I see a lot of code, but no question..  You might want to start by reading through Hello Tab Layout: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html  The developer docs have great tutorials for each of the view types.

Comment: Sorry I had posted a question but I was suggested to put the code. I did review the Hello tab layout question but somehow I am new to the idea of having two layouts in one window. My problem with this is that I am trying to get a list view inside a tab view. I was sucesful in getting the tab view working but when I tried to incorporate the list view inside one of the tab it was not working out properly. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What was suggested was that you should put less code to **keep only the parts relevant to the question**, not keep only all the code and delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you look at two of my blog articles it might give you some helpful ideas.
check out [multiple-android-activities](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)
also take a look at the Configuring Android Listview article as well.
Hope it helps.